# shutil.copy2 is copying only one file and stops, instead copying the whole files from loop

Tags: python, shutil

I have two codes with 1 function(copying the files from `src` folder, which are existing in cells `product_number`)

The problem is that the code is copying only 1 file and stops copying without finishing the program.

How can I fix that?

```
def copy_images(excel_path):
    src = r'D:\src_img'
    destination_folder = r'D:\dest_img'

    copy_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_path)
    data_list = copy_file.active

    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for name in files:
            filename = os.path.join(path, name)
            for row in range(2, data_list.max_row + 1):
                product_number = str(data_list.cell(row, 1).value)

                if product_number in filename:
                    full_dest_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, filename.lstrip(src).lstrip('/'))

                    dirname = os.path.dirname(full_dest_path)
                    if not os.path.exists(dirname):
                        os.makedirs(dirname)

                        shutil.copy2(filename, full_dest_path)


def update_images(excel_path):
    src = r'D:\src_img'
    dest = r'D:\dest_img'

    copy_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_path)
    data_list = copy_file.active

    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for name in files:
            filename = os.path.join(path, name)
            for row in range(2, data_list.max_row + 1):
                product_number = str(data_list.cell(row, 1).value)

                if product_number in filename:
                    if not os.path.exists(dest):
                        os.makedirs(dest)

                        shutil.copy2(filename, os.path.join(dest, name))
```

Comment: Sort out your indenting? The `shutils.copy2` line is only executed if the target folder doesn’t exist - that’s only once because for the next file in the source folder the target folder will exist.

Comment: Thank you, but now came other problem. It copies more files(rows) than are available in this loop. I want to be copied 300(if they are existing) from 500. Now it is copying the maximum(500). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outdent the `shutil.copy2()` lines to the same level as the `if` statement so they are executed regardless of whether or not the directory exists.

Comment: Thank you, but now came other problem.

It copies more files(rows) than are available in this loop. I want to be copied 300(if they are existing) from 500. Now it is copying the maximum(500).

How can I fix that?

Comment: That’s a different question: create a new question with your latest code.

Comment: I thought so too, but decided to ask. If you have wish and time, you can check my second question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030188/shutil-copy2-copies-more-files-than-there-are-in-the-loop   PS: I don't have score to give you reputation too.